# Dropdownlist with Add and Remove function

Tags: yii, yii-components

I am using the code below display multiple selected values for users to choose from.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'site_staff'); ?>
    <?php //echo $form->textField($model,'site_staff',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
    <?php //echo $form->dropDownList($model,'site_staff', CHtml::listData(Biodata::model()->findAll(), 'full_name', 'full_name'), array('empty'=>'Select')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'site_staff',CHtml::listData(Biodata::model()->findAll(),'full_name','full_name'),array('multiple'=>'true','prompt'=>'select ','selected'=>'selected'));?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'site_staff'); ?>
</div>
```

I am trying to achieve the following but have no idea how to go about:
1) Add and remove function
- When a user choose one or more, by clicking "Add", will display the selected value in another dropdown list
- User can also remove any selected data in the latter dropdown list

So far, the single dropdown works well but users need to use CTRL-CLICK to select more than one option which is not a feasible way of selecting.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hii you can also use a `multiselect dropdown` for this.

Use `yii` `select2` for this.

this is nice `extension` Please read more about this from here
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/select2/